# Retrofit 2 - send REQUEST representation

Tags: request, retrofit2

I'm having Error 500 when trying to connect to service, and I believe I´m not sending all the info it needs to work because I use SOAPUI and it responds OK.
This is the snapshot from SOAPUI:
[snapshot from SOAPUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt2yF.jpg)

So, my question is how to add the request representation from SOAPUI into the service. this is my service:

```
public interface ValidarDNIService {
@Headers({
        "Accept: application/xml",
        "Content-Type: text/xml",
        "Accept-Charset: utf-8"

})
@POST("/API/CustomerManagement/v1/customer/verify")
Call<VerifiyCustomerCompleteResponse> validarDNI(@Body NationalIdentityCardIdentification body);
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED.
Just copied the SOAPAction from SOAP UI and created a "SOAPAction" parameter as a header